# javaFX controllers doesn't communicate which each other

Tags: javafx

i have a problem with javaFX.I'm doing calculator and i divide my app between 3 FXML files(1 is a controller which controlls only numbers and operators, 2 is a controller for textfield which is result field, and last one should let them communicate which each other).

I can not manage how can i write my own method which for example put number "3" when i press number 3 in textfield-which is in other FXML and has its own fxml file.There is a nullpointer exception so i suppose im not initializing this textfield.Please help me with this problem.Is there any way to write my own method(in this example i wrote showDigit()) in MainController class - this method should set Text to textfield after pressing button - for example button 2 will put "2" in textfield.

Below I've pasted my code.

```
package pl.calculator.controller;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
public class MainPaneController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private TextPaneController textPaneController;

@FXML
private CalculatorPaneController calculatorPaneController;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    /*calculatorPaneController.getButtonZero().setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

            textPaneController.getTextFieldExpression().setText("example");
        }
    });*/  --- < THIS WORKS

}
}
```

FXML for MainController

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
fx:controller="pl.calculator.controller.MainPaneController">
<children>
    <fx:include fx:id="textPane" source="TextPane.fxml" />
    <fx:include fx:id="calculatorPane" source="CalculatorPane.fxml" />
</children>
</VBox>
```

Number and operation controller:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;  
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

public class CalculatorPaneController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private Button buttonFour;

@FXML
private Button buttonSix;

@FXML
private Button buttonDivide;

@FXML
private Button buttonOne;

@FXML
private Button buttonCloseBracket;

@FXML
private Button buttonDot;

@FXML
private Button buttonClear;

@FXML
private Button buttonTwo;

@FXML
private Button buttonSeven;

@FXML
private Button buttonOpenBracket;

@FXML
private Button buttonThree;

@FXML
private Button buttonMultiply;

@FXML
private Button buttonSubtract;

@FXML
private Button buttonEight;

@FXML
private Button buttonEqual;

@FXML
private Button buttonNine;

@FXML
private Button buttonZero;

@FXML
private Button buttonMemory;

@FXML
private Button buttonFive;

@FXML
private GridPane gridPane;

@FXML
private Button buttonAdd;

@FXML
private TextPaneController textPaneController;

@FXML
private CalculatorPaneController calculatorPaneController;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {


}

@FXML
private void showDigit(ActionEvent event) {

    textPaneController.getTextFieldExpression().setText("s");

} <---------THIS ONE DOESNT WORK 

public Button getButtonFour() {
    return buttonFour;
}

public void setButtonFour(Button buttonFour) {
    this.buttonFour = buttonFour;
}

public Button getButtonSix() {
    return buttonSix;
}

public void setButtonSix(Button buttonSix) {
    this.buttonSix = buttonSix;
}

public Button getButtonDivide() {
    return buttonDivide;
}

public void setButtonDivide(Button buttonDivide) {
    this.buttonDivide = buttonDivide;
}

public Button getButtonOne() {
    return buttonOne;
}

public void setButtonOne(Button buttonOne) {
    this.buttonOne = buttonOne;
}

public Button getButtonCloseBracket() {
    return buttonCloseBracket;
}

public void setButtonCloseBracket(Button buttonCloseBracket) {
    this.buttonCloseBracket = buttonCloseBracket;
}

public Button getButtonDot() {
    return buttonDot;
}

public void setButtonDot(Button buttonDot) {
    this.buttonDot = buttonDot;
}

public Button getButtonClear() {
    return buttonClear;
}

public void setButtonClear(Button buttonClear) {
    this.buttonClear = buttonClear;
}

public Button getButtonTwo() {
    return buttonTwo;
}

public void setButtonTwo(Button buttonTwo) {
    this.buttonTwo = buttonTwo;
}

public Button getButtonSeven() {
    return buttonSeven;
}

public void setButtonSeven(Button buttonSeven) {
    this.buttonSeven = buttonSeven;
}

public Button getButtonOpenBracket() {
    return buttonOpenBracket;
}

public void setButtonOpenBracket(Button buttonOpenBracket) {
    this.buttonOpenBracket = buttonOpenBracket;
}

public Button getButtonThree() {
    return buttonThree;
}

public void setButtonThree(Button buttonThree) {
    this.buttonThree = buttonThree;
}

public Button getButtonMultiply() {
    return buttonMultiply;
}

public void setButtonMultiply(Button buttonMultiply) {
    this.buttonMultiply = buttonMultiply;
}

public Button getButtonSubtract() {
    return buttonSubtract;
}

public void setButtonSubtract(Button buttonSubtract) {
    this.buttonSubtract = buttonSubtract;
}

public Button getButtonEight() {
    return buttonEight;
}

public void setButtonEight(Button buttonEight) {
    this.buttonEight = buttonEight;
}

public Button getButtonEqual() {
    return buttonEqual;
}

public void setButtonEqual(Button buttonEqual) {
    this.buttonEqual = buttonEqual;
}

public Button getButtonNine() {
    return buttonNine;
}

public void setButtonNine(Button buttonNine) {
    this.buttonNine = buttonNine;
}

public Button getButtonZero() {
    return buttonZero;
}

public void setButtonZero(Button buttonZero) {
    this.buttonZero = buttonZero;
}

public Button getButtonMemory() {
    return buttonMemory;
}

public void setButtonMemory(Button buttonMemory) {
    this.buttonMemory = buttonMemory;
}

public Button getButtonFive() {
    return buttonFive;
}

public void setButtonFive(Button buttonFive) {
    this.buttonFive = buttonFive;
}

public GridPane getGridPane() {
    return gridPane;
}

public void setGridPane(GridPane gridPane) {
    this.gridPane = gridPane;
}

public Button getButtonAdd() {
    return buttonAdd;
}

public void setButtonAdd(Button buttonAdd) {
    this.buttonAdd = buttonAdd;
}

}
```

FXML for operation and number controller:

```
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<GridPane fx:id="gridPane" prefHeight="308.0" prefWidth="375.0"    xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"     fx:controller="pl.calculator.controller.CalculatorPaneController">
  <children>
  <Button fx:id="buttonOne" minHeight="40.0" minWidth="40.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#showDigit" text="1" />
  <Button fx:id="buttonFour" minHeight="40.0" minWidth="40.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="4" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
  <Button fx:id="buttonTwo" minHeight="40.0" minWidth="40.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="2" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
  <Button fx:id="buttonSeven" minHeight="40.0" minWidth="40.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="7" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
  <Button fx:id="buttonFive" minHeight="40.0" minWidth="40.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="5" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
  <Button fx:id="buttonEight" minHeight="40.0" minWidth="40.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="8" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
  <Button fx:id="buttonThree" minHeight="40.0" minWidth="40.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="3" GridPane.columnIndex="2" />
  <Button fx:id="buttonSix" minHeight="40.0" minWidth="40.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="6" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
  <Button fx:id="buttonNine" minHeight="40.0" minWidth="40.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="9" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
  <Button fx:id="buttonZero" minHeight="40.0" minWidth="40.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="0" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
  <Button fx:id="buttonDot" minHeight="40.0" minWidth="40.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="." GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
  <Button fx:id="buttonEqual" minHeight="40.0" minWidth="40.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="=" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
  <Button fx:id="buttonDivide" minHeight="40.0" minWidth="40.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="/" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
  <Button fx:id="buttonMultiply" minHeight="40.0" minWidth="40.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="*" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
  <Button fx:id="buttonSubtract" minHeight="40.0" minWidth="40.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="-" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
  <Button fx:id="buttonAdd" minHeight="40.0" minWidth="40.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="+" GridPane.columnIndex="3" />
  <Button fx:id="buttonCloseBracket" minHeight="40.0" minWidth="40.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text=")" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
  <Button fx:id="buttonOpenBracket" minHeight="40.0" minWidth="40.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="(" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
  <Button fx:id="buttonMemory" minHeight="40.0" minWidth="40.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="M" GridPane.columnIndex="4" />
  <Button fx:id="buttonClear" minHeight="40.0" minWidth="40.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="C" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
   </children>
   <columnConstraints>
   <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
   <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
   <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
   </columnConstraints>
   <rowConstraints>
   <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    </rowConstraints>
    </GridPane>
```

Controller for textfields(results)

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class TextPaneController {

@FXML
private Label labelExpression;

@FXML
private TextField textFieldOnp;

@FXML
private Label labelOnp;

@FXML
private TextField textFieldExpression;


public Label getLabelExpression() {
    return labelExpression;
}

public void setLableExpression(Label lableExpression) {
    this.labelExpression = lableExpression;
}

public TextField getTextFieldOnp() {
    return textFieldOnp;
}

public void setTextFieldOnp(TextField textFieldOnp) {
    this.textFieldOnp = textFieldOnp;
}

public Label getLabelOnp() {
    return labelOnp;
}

public void setLabelOnp(Label labelOnp) {
    this.labelOnp = labelOnp;
}

public TextField getTextFieldExpression() {
    return textFieldExpression;
}

public void setTextFieldExpression(TextField textFieldExpression) {
    this.textFieldExpression = textFieldExpression;
}
}
```

FXML File for TExt:

```
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

 <AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="89.0" prefWidth="349.0"  xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="pl.calculator.controller.TextPaneController">
  <children>
  <Label fx:id="lableExpression" layoutX="21.0" layoutY="14.0" text="Wprowadź wyrażenie:" />
  <Label fx:id="labelOnp" layoutX="213.0" layoutY="14.0" text="Wyrażenie ONP" />
    <TextField fx:id="textFieldExpression" layoutX="5.0" layoutY="45.0" />
    <TextField fx:id="textFieldOnp" editable="false" layoutX="180.0" layoutY="45.0" />
</children>
</AnchorPane>
```

and stack trace:

```
TextField[id=textFieldExpression, styleClass=text-input text-field]
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1800(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pl.calculator.controller.CalculatorPaneController.showDigit(CalculatorPaneController.java:89)
    ... 57 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FXML file CalculatorPane.fxml doesn't have an `<fx:include fx:id="textPane" ... />`, so the associated controller doesn't get a `textPaneController` injected into it. Thus `textPaneController` in `CalculatorPaneController` is `null`, and you get the `NullPointerException`.

A way to update the value from the `CalculatorPaneController` is to give both controllers a shared data model, and update the model. So you could do something like

```
public class DataModel {

    private final StringProperty text = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public StringProperty textProperty() {
        return text ;
    }

    public final String getText() {
        return textProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setText(String text) {
        textProperty().set(text);
    }

    // other properties as needed...
}
```

Then you controllers can do

```
public class TextPaneController {

    private DataModel model ;

    @FXML
    private TextField textFieldExpression ;

    // etc ...

    public void setModel(DataModel model) {
        this.model = model ;
        textFieldExpression.textProperty().bindBidirectional(model.textProperty());
    }
}
```

and

```
public class CalculatorPaneController {

    private DataModel model ;

    public void setModel(DataModel model) {
        this.model = model ;
    }

    // ...

    @FXML
    private void showDigit(ActionEvent event) {

        model.setText("s");

    }
}
```

Finally, you tie everything together in the main controller's initialize method:

```
public class MainPaneController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TextPaneController textPaneController;

    @FXML
    private CalculatorPaneController calculatorPaneController;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        DataModel model = new DataModel();
        textPaneController.setModel(model);
        calculatorPaneController.setModel(model);

    }

}
```

You really don't need (and shouldn't have) all the get/set methods for the controls in the controllers. Those should be kept private and not exposed outside the controller.

Comment: thank you very much James for your help.Please tell me should i delete all getters/setter which im not using right?I'm learning java right now so im not sure if i understand it well...maybe for beginners it's good to delete get/set methods after writing whole application(cos i do not have experience yet and i can not know which i'll be using).

Comment: Yes, I would not define getters and setters for the controls.

Comment: i got method like this:@FXML
 public void printExpression(ActionEvent event) {

  String digit = ((Button) event.getSource()).getText();
  String text = model.getText();
  String newText = text + digit;
  model.setText(newText);
  /*String digit = ((Button) event.getSource()).getText();
  String text = textFieldExpression.getText();
  String newText = text + digit;
  textFieldExpression.setText(newText);*/

 }
when i press for example 3 it prints null3... can u help me understand what im doing wrong?thanks in advance

Comment: i've already manage with problem above.. now i dont know how to print my result variable value to other textfield.when im calculating expression it appears in my textFieldExpression not in textFieldResult.i know that is because model is set for textFieldExpression not result but how can i change it? how can i transfer value of variable result to other textField?regards